# Finding the Equation of a Plane provided with normal vector and point

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Okay, so I am trying to find an equation of a plane that passes through the point (-1,3,5) and has a normal vector of <2,4,-3>.

The format of the answer must be such that

_____x  + _____y  +  ______z  +1 = 0

**My work so far**

Okay, so I attempted to start using point-normal form for the plane. Given that we already know the attitude numbers to be [2,4,-3] from the normal vector.

Working with this I get:

2(x+1) + 4(y-3) -3(z-5) = 0
Converting to standard form I get 2x +4y -3z +5=0

My problem is that I can not figure out how to get 1 as the constant rather than 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've made a mistake with your expansion:
$$2(x+1)+4(y-3)-3(z-5)=0$$
$$2x+4y-3z\color{#bb0000}{+5}=0$$

To get it in the form required, just simply divide the whole equation by $5$:
$$2x+4y-3z+5=0$$
$$\frac{2x+4y-3z+5}{5}=\frac{0}{5}$$
$$\frac{2}{5}x+\frac{4}{5}y-\frac{3}{5}z+1=0$$
Which is in the form $ax+by+cz+1=0$.

Comment: Yes I did, I had 5 originally not -5. Can't believe I didn't think to divide. Such a simple answer

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just divide what you already have by $-5$?